# View/edit ID3 data for MP3 files

Tags: c#, .net, mp3, id3

What's a quick and easy way to view and edit ID3 tags (artist, album, etc.) using C#?

Answer (score 196, accepted):

Thirding [TagLib Sharp](https://github.com/mono/taglib-sharp).

```
TagLib.File f = TagLib.File.Create(path);
f.Tag.Album = "New Album Title";
f.Save();
```

Comment: Can anybody tell me how to set Artist property? There are a lot of related properties (FirstArtist, Artist, JointedArtists, FirstPerformer) and almost all of them are read-only or deprecated...

Comment: A bit late, but you can add the performers/artists by the following: mp3.Tag.Performers = new string[] { "Performer 1", "Performer 2", "Performer 3" };

Comment: Does this library support modern ID3v2 tags? Simucal's snippet suggests not (unless he just took part of it).

Comment: TagLib is GPL.  This is hardly an appropriate answer here.

Answer (score 67):

[TagLib Sharp](http://www.novell.com/products/linuxpackages/opensuse11.1/taglib-sharp.html) is pretty popular.

As a side note, if you wanted to take a quick and dirty peek at doing it yourself.. here is a C# snippet I found to read an mp3's tag info.

```
class MusicID3Tag

{

    public byte[] TAGID = new byte[3];      //  3
    public byte[] Title = new byte[30];     //  30
    public byte[] Artist = new byte[30];    //  30 
    public byte[] Album = new byte[30];     //  30 
    public byte[] Year = new byte[4];       //  4 
    public byte[] Comment = new byte[30];   //  30 
    public byte[] Genre = new byte[1];      //  1

}

string filePath = @"C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Documents\My Music\Sample Music\041105.mp3";

        using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(filePath))
        {
            if (fs.Length >= 128)
            {
                MusicID3Tag tag = new MusicID3Tag();
                fs.Seek(-128, SeekOrigin.End);
                fs.Read(tag.TAGID, 0, tag.TAGID.Length);
                fs.Read(tag.Title, 0, tag.Title.Length);
                fs.Read(tag.Artist, 0, tag.Artist.Length);
                fs.Read(tag.Album, 0, tag.Album.Length);
                fs.Read(tag.Year, 0, tag.Year.Length);
                fs.Read(tag.Comment, 0, tag.Comment.Length);
                fs.Read(tag.Genre, 0, tag.Genre.Length);
                string theTAGID = Encoding.Default.GetString(tag.TAGID);

                if (theTAGID.Equals("TAG"))
                {
                    string Title = Encoding.Default.GetString(tag.Title);
                    string Artist = Encoding.Default.GetString(tag.Artist);
                    string Album = Encoding.Default.GetString(tag.Album);
                    string Year = Encoding.Default.GetString(tag.Year);
                    string Comment = Encoding.Default.GetString(tag.Comment);
                    string Genre = Encoding.Default.GetString(tag.Genre);

                    Console.WriteLine(Title);
                    Console.WriteLine(Artist);
                    Console.WriteLine(Album);
                    Console.WriteLine(Year);
                    Console.WriteLine(Comment);
                    Console.WriteLine(Genre);
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: That is only for ID3v1. v2 has another structure, it's in the beginning of the file (as opposed to v1 which was in the end) and has variable length (v1 is always 128 bytes).

Comment: it's very too long solution & not optimized .
http://stackoverflow.com/a/4361634/1395101

Comment: `Encoding.Default` can be replaced with `Encoding.UTF8`. For more information visit: http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/practical-an-id3-parser.html

Answer (score 26):

<s>[UltraID3Lib](http://UltraID3Lib.com)...</s>

Be aware that UltraID3Lib is no longer officially available, and thus no longer maintained. See comments below for the link to a Github project that includes this library

```
//using HundredMilesSoftware.UltraID3Lib;
UltraID3 u = new UltraID3();
u.Read(@"C:\mp3\song.mp3");
//view
Console.WriteLine(u.Artist);
//edit
u.Artist = "New Artist";
u.Write();
```

Comment: +1 This is the best library by far - since 'UltraID3Lib supports most all of the seventy-four types of frames specified in the ID3 v2.3' as well as the early ID3v1 tags. Best answer.

Comment: +1 This is much easier to use and simpler way to deal with mp3 metadata

Comment: I used this recently and it works awesome and does not burden the process. It's fast and easy to use and accounts for just about every tag that exists in ID3 versions 1 and 2 (you can use both at once or just one or the other). It does way more than I needed. It also had a very comprehensive help file. I will recommend this to everyone.

Comment: Greetings; Link is inaccessible. Is UltraID3Lib Discontinued?

Comment: I found a version of UltraID3Lib included in this GitHub project.  https://github.com/clementboone/MyWindowsMediaPlayer
The project contains an UltraID3Lib folder that is the complete contents of the zip file that used to be available.

Comment: It should go without saying that relying a library that is no longer publicly available or maintained probably isn't an ideal solution for most situations

Answer (score 15):

[TagLib Sharp](http://www.novell.com/products/linuxpackages/opensuse11.1/taglib-sharp.html) has support for reading ID3 tags.

Comment: I started using TagLib sharp based on the recommendation here and it worked great for my application (which was read-only of MP3 info).

Comment: See hewins's answer below for the new link location

Answer (score 2):

I wrapped mp3 decoder library and made it available for .net developers.  You can find it here:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/mpg123net/

Included are the samples to convert mp3 file to PCM, and read ID3 tags.

Answer (score 2):

[ID3.NET](http://id3.codeplex.com/) implemented ID3v1.x and ID3v2.3 and supports read/write operations on the ID3 section in MP3 files.
There's also a [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ID3/) available.

Answer (score 1):

[Audio Tools Library (ATL)](https://github.com/Zeugma440/atldotnet) is the best. Don't use TagLib sharp. Its has limited support and can't handle chapters. The nuget package is [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/z440.atl.core/) for ATL. I tried several things, but ATL was the only one that could do everything I needed.