# Edit music metadata with c#

Tags: c#, .net, file-io, metadata

how can i access the summary of a file like music file (any format) and edit it and especially the artwork of this file(the photo that are included in the file) and edit it too?
thanks.

Comment: You're making some false assumptions about music files.

Comment: A similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68283/view-edit-mp3-id3-data-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably need to read up on the specification for whatever music file format you're using.  Each music format has a different metadata format and compression/encoding scheme.  Some formats might have libraries available for maniuplating the files, and some might have to be manipulated by hand.

For example, try searching google for "mp3 spec" or "mp3 file format"

Answer (score 2):

May I recommend [TagLib Sharp](http://developer.novell.com/wiki/index.php/TagLib_Sharp) for mp3 tag editing. Very powerful and easy to use with clear documentation.

Answer (score 1):

There is a project on [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/csid3lib) that allows you to edit ID3 tags for MP3 files, but ive never used it, so I cant vouch for how good it is.