# Mp3 Header information edit

Tags: .net, mp3

I want to edit the header information of an existing MP3 file. Can any one suggest how to achieve it in C#.net?

I want to include some details in header like, company name, description, website link etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [View/edit ID3 data for MP3 files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68283/view-edit-id3-data-for-mp3-files)

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](http://devhood.com/Tutorials/tutorial_details.aspx?tutorial_id=79) out. You are then free to [manipulate bits and bytes](http://www.byteblocks.com/post/2009/03/21/Manipulating-Bits-and-Bytes-With-C.aspx). If you are referring to ID3 data instead, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68283/view-edit-mp3-id3-data-in-c).