# Where can I find tag lib sharp examples?

Tags: c#, taglib-sharp

I have been searching for ID3 editors for my music manager project. It seems that **taglib sharp** is the popular choice. I googled a lot and could not find any examples of using it.

Can some one point me to some examples showing the library usage ?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Well without knowing exactly what you want to do all I can offer is my code.

You create a `TagLib` File object from the actual mp3 file. This reads the file and extracts the tag data:

```
TagLib.File tagFile = TagLib.File.Create(track); // track is the name of the mp3
```

Then to get a tag value:

```
uint year = tagFile.Tag.Year;
```

You set the tags like this:

```
tagFile.Tag.Year = year;
```

and then save the changes:

```
tagFile.Save();
```

Comment: Thanks of @ChrisF if u need to knowledge for editing image cover , u can go to this topic = > http://stackoverflow.com/a/30285220/1395101