# Error with UltraID3Lib VB

Tags: vb.net, tags, mp3

Well I get this error (The ID3v2TagVersions value of '4' (4) is not valid for this operation.) with UltraID3Lib on Visual Basic 2013. I want to use this library (dll) so i can edit my mp3 tags in a mp3 file. Although I achived changing the tags , when i use the Clear() sub and then retry to change the tags i get this error. Can anyone help me ?

My Code

```
    Private Sub btnExecute_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExecute.Click
        Dim Artist As String = ""
        Dim Title As String = ""
        Dim MP3TagEditor As New UltraID3
        For Each Path In MP3List
            MP3TagEditor.Read(Path)
            Title = "Somthing"
            Artist = "Somthing"
            MP3TagEditor.ID3v2Tag.Title = Title
            MP3TagEditor.ID3v2Tag.Artist = Artist
            MP3TagEditor.Clear()
            MP3TagEditor.Write()
        Next
        MsgBox("Tags Added", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Success")
End Sub
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Dim sTitle As String = "No Name"
Dim sSinger As String = ""
Dim sAlbum As String = ""
Dim sYear As String = ""
Dim sComm As String = ""
Dim MP3Tag As New UltraID3
                MP3Tag.Read(YOUR_PATH)

                Try
                    Dim pics = MP3Tag.ID3v2Tag.Frames.GetFrames(CommonMultipleInstanceID3v2FrameTypes.Picture)
                    AlbumPic.Image = CType(pics(0), ID3v2PictureFrame).Picture
                Catch ex As Exception
                    AlbumPic.Image = My.Resources.FlatCD
                End Try
                Try
                    sTitle = MP3Tag.Title
                    sSinger = MP3Tag.Artist
                    sAlbum = MP3Tag.Album
                Catch ex As Exception

                End Try
```

Comment: Well , the thing is that, I Dont want to read the Tags from the file , I need to add tags to it. Example:"I dont want to do the **sTitle = MP3Tag.Title** I need to do the **MP3Tag.Title = sTitle** and then **MP3Tag.Write()** . But When i Do the **MP3Tag.Clear()** I will get an error trying to manipulate the tags

Comment: Try without Clear() function.

Comment: Well I need that Class , thats why Im using it . I now use a secondary class that I created just to clear the Tags but i dont think it is realy doing what i want it to do. So thats why I need to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

You cannot read ID3v2.4 tags from an MP3 file with UltraID3Lib. It doesn't support it yet. (As of 31/12/2015).

But there is an alternative, which, in my humble opinion is even better, stable and efficacious:

- [TagLib-Sharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/taglib/)

It supports many other tag types as well apart from ID3, i.e, MP3 Files.
A quick example to get you on the way:

```
Dim f As TagLib.File = TagLib.File.Create("someFile.mp3")
Dim artist As String = f.Tag.JoinedPerformers
Dim title As String = f.Tag.Title
```

More resources for TagLib-Sharp:

- [Where can I find tag lib sharp examples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361587/where-can-i-find-tag-lib-sharp-examples)
- [Set Bitmap as cover art for MP3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30285069/set-bitmap-as-cover-art-for-mp3)