# Set Bitmap as cover art for MP3

Tags: c#, bitmap, taglib-sharp

I have been trying to set a bitmap as cover art for a MP3 but I can't seem to get it working. It isn't throwing any errors but when I play the MP3 the bitmap isn't showing.

This is what I currently have:

```
TagLib.File f = TagLib.File.Create("song.mp3");

Image currentImage = getAlbumArt(result.passedAlbumID);
Picture pic = new Picture();
pic.Type = PictureType.FrontCover;
pic.MimeType = System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg;
pic.Description = "Cover";
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
currentImage.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
ms.Position = 0;
pic.Data = ByteVector.FromStream(ms);
f.Tag.Pictures = new IPicture[1] { pic };
pictureBox1.Image = currentImage; //testing the image is correct

f.Save();
ms.Close();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm using the following code and everything works fine for me:

```
TagLib.File file = TagLib.File.Create(/*path to your mp3 file*/);
TagLib.Picture pic = new TagLib.Picture();
pic.Type = TagLib.PictureType.FrontCover;
pic.Description = "Cover";
pic.MimeType = System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg;
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
/*your image*/.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
ms.Position = 0;
pic.Data = TagLib.ByteVector.FromStream(ms);
file.Tag.Pictures = new TagLib.IPicture[] { pic };
file.Save();
ms.Close();
```

According to your provided code, the only thing I noticed is, that my code is using following line

```
file.Tag.Pictures = new TagLib.IPicture[] { pic };
```

instead of

```
f.Tag.Pictures = new TagLib.IPicture[1] { pic };
```

So simply try, if it works when you remove the `1` inside the square brackets.