# How do I use taglib-sharp?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, taglib-sharp

I'm having a bunch of troubles with this library (obviously because I'm a newbie). I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2015.

First of all I have absolutely no idea on how to add this library to my project. I didn't find anything helpful on Google, either.

And second, I've found two different libraries - `taglib-sharp-master` and `taglib-sharp-2.1.0.0-windows`. Which one should I use?

Answer (score 30):

There are a few things you'll want to do in order to get `taglib-sharp` working in your project.

Firstly, you need to stick to a particular project type. Next, you are to install the suitable library version for that project. Next, you can use the library as you wish to. I shall also provide a minimal example to get you started and a link to a bunch of examples which you might find of help.

#### Choosing the correct version of TagLib:

There's some ambiguity in your question as you have tagged it with both [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) and [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23). If you want to use [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) in your project, then your best bet is to use the `taglib` library. *Note: Not the 'sharp' version.*

However, almost the entire question and its title speaks of `taglib-sharp`. Given that, I shall presume that you are using [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) for your project. Accordingly, your project is a `.NET C#` project. You can obviate the quandary over selecting the project type. Any of the project types (`WinForms`, `WPF`, `Console Application` will work just fine as `taglib-sharp` is just an off-screen library.

And also, FYI, both taglib-sharp-master and taglib-sharp-2.1.0.0-windows are essentially the same stuff. The former is probably the latest version since the latter specifies a definite version 2.1.0.0. But again, 2.1.0.0 has long been the latest version of taglib-sharp. So, use either, and you should be fine.

#### Installing TagLib-Sharp a.k.a. TagLib#:

Next up, you must install `TagLib-Sharp` to your project. There are a few ways to do so:

- Install it via Nuget
- Add a reference to the binary

♦  **Installing via Nuget:**

This is probably the recommended way of installing any library/component in Visual Studio. Head over to the Nuget Package Manager Console. Once there, type in:

```
Install-Package taglib
```

Nuget Package link: [Taglib-Sharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/taglib/).

and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

For more information on the `Nuget Package Manager Console`, how to open it and use it, visit [this link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/22da8c/package-manager-console-in-visual-studio/).

You can also add it with the help of the Nuget Package Manager (GUI). Open the Package Manager and search for "taglib-sharp". Install the appropriate package that shows in the search results.

For more information on the `Nuget Package Manager`, how to open and use it, visit [this link](https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/tools/package-manager-ui).

♦  **Downloading the binary and adding a reference to it directly:**

You can download the latest version of the `taglib-sharp` binaries [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20151130093954/http://download.banshee.fm/taglib-sharp/2.1.0.0/taglib-sharp-2.1.0.0-windows.zip). The download is a `.zip` archive. Unzip the file.

In the unzipped folder, head over to `\Libraries`. There, find the `taglib-sharp.dll` file. Keep a note of where the file is located.

Next, in Visual Studio, go to **Project > Add Reference**.

There, in the left panel, select **Browse**. Now in the dialog buttons section, click **browse** and locate the `.dll` file you extracted from the `.zip` archive. Make sure the CheckBox next to it is checked:

[image: Add Reference Dialog]

Click OK.

Now you are all set to use `TagLib-Sharp`.

#### Using TagLib-Sharp (Examples):

The minimal example of using the library would be opening a file and editing its `Title` property and retrieving the `Year` property:

```
var file = TagLib.File.Create("<yourFile.mp3>"); // Change file path accordingly.

file.Tag.Title = "My Own Song";

var year = file.Tag.Year;

// Save Changes:
file.Save();
```

You can also find a similar example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4361634/4546874) to get your started.

More examples:

- [Set Bitmap as cover art for MP3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30285069/set-bitmap-as-cover-art-for-mp3/30285220#30285220)
- https://github.com/mono/taglib-sharp/tree/master/examples
- https://www.codeproject.com/messages/3009089/extracting-id3-albumart-with-taglib-sharp.aspx

If you have further queries, feel free to ask in the comments below. And also, if the question deserves a separate thread, word it properly and ask it here on Stack Overflow itself.

Hope this answer helps. :)

Comment: Tried the Nuget `Install-Package taglib-sharp` command and it didn't work. It seems like it was changed to `Install-Package taglib`

Comment: @Eugene Yeah, so it seems. It might as well have been a mistake on my part. I wonder if it was `taglib` all along. But there's also a unmanaged `taglib` library. Anyway, I'll fix it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: The Binary file can be now found here: https://web.archive.org/web/20151130093954/http://download.banshee.fm/taglib-sharp/2.1.0.0/taglib-sharp-2.1.0.0-windows.zip

Comment: use Find-Package tablib to find the correct package, which is currently TagLibSharp, not taglib or taglib-sharp