# Edit M4V Video Metadata

Tags: c#, ruby, file, video, metadata

So far my google-fu has failed me, so I'm hoping someone here can help:

How can I programmatically modify video metadata (specifically in my case, m4v video files)?

I'm most familiar with Ruby and C#, but I can be fairly language agnostic on this -- that is, if there's a specific language that is good at modifying file metadata, I have no problems spending the required time to learn it well enough to accomplish what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 4):

This question is pretty similar to:

[View/edit ID3 data for MP3 files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68283/view-edit-id3-data-for-mp3-files)

I have searched for the library so you dont have to:

http://download.banshee.fm/taglib-sharp/

Even tho it has linux on its name it is for mono, so it should compile fine in Visual Studio :)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Do video files use the same ID3 tagging scheme as MP3 files?  I came across that question as well, but assumed (possibly incorrectly) that MP3 **audio** files and MP4 **video** files used different metadata formats.

Comment: As far as i know, yes. ID3 tags are same for audio and video.

Comment: Hmm, interesting.  That would certainly make these easier.  I'll check it out and report back.

Comment: As i stated in my answer... Hope it helps ;)

Answer (score 1):

Consider asking http://www.ffmpeg.org/contact.html in #ffmpeg

I don't think they use ID3 tags.

Comment: MP4 allows for ID3 Tag embedding. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3#Implementation_in_non-mp3s_and_alternatives