# Changing AVI File Title Property with C#

Tags: c#, avi, file-properties

Are there any libraries for C# (maybe ffmpeg, never really used it) that could view and set the Title, Artist, and other such properties of an AVI file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thirding [TagLib Sharp](http://www.novell.com/products/linuxpackages/opensuse11.1/taglib-sharp.html).

```
TagLib.File f = TagLib.File.Create(path);
f.Tag.Album = "New Album Title";
f.Save();
```

The answer was taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/281413/601179).

Comment: thanks for the tip, the library is great, the documentation isn't...