# How to encode string for ID3 tags in C#

Tags: c#, encoding, id3

I am having problems with encoding in ID3 tags. I query a webservice which returns back some XML including a node such as the one below:

```
<name>Blue Öyster Cult</name>
```

I am then using this information to update my ID3 tags. The problem is that the tag is updated as:

```
Blue Ã–yster Cult
```

I know this is an encoding issue, but I'm struggling to work out how to get it to work. My understanding is that ID3 tags need to be encoded as ISO-8859-1.

I wrote this code, but it makes no difference:

```
Encoding newEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
Encoding utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;
byte[] utfBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(newArtistName);
byte[] asciBytes = Encoding.Convert(utf8, newEncoding, utfBytes);
string encodedArtistName = newEncoding.GetString(asciBytes);
```

Is this in the right direction or not?

Any advice much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using ID3v1 or ID3v2?  ID3v1 is ASCII-only, while ID3v2 can use Unicode encodings.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3#ID3v2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue that I was having was actually prior to saving to the ID3 tags. The XML I was receiving was set to UTF-8, but the WebClient requesting the page was not. Adding the second line shown here resolved the problem.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();    
client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
String htmlCode = client.DownloadString(requestURL);
```

When the value is extracting from this XML, it has the correct encoding to be saved to the files ID3 tag.

Answer (score 2):

## ID3 v2

Textual frames are marked with an encoding byte.

```
$00 – ISO-8859-1 (ASCII).
$01 – UCS-2 (UTF-16 encoded Unicode with BOM), in ID3v2.2 and ID3v2.3.
$02 – UTF-16BE encoded Unicode without BOM, in ID3v2.4.
$03 – UTF-8 encoded Unicode, in ID3v2.4.
```

Detailed specification can be found at http://id3.org/id3v2-00.

---

Also see [View/edit ID3 data for MP3 files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68283/view-edit-id3-data-for-mp3-files) - post with similar issue.

Comment: If the Wikipedia article is correct, it's not always Unicode, but there is an encoding byte that chooses its encoding. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3#ID3v2