# How do I install a C# class library in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, class-library

I am trying to use a class library which I found [on a different question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/281381/1934286).

I am quite new to C#, Visual Studio, and OOP in general, so please excuse me if this is not the right question.

I followed the link and downloaded the zip. The help file does not seem to contain any directions on how to get Visual Studio to utilize the library. I figure that I have to tell it to use the library somehow, but I really don't know what to do. Or maybe I need to copy the .dll to a specific folder. I also assume I need `using ...` in the top of the .cs files that use it.

How can I use this library in a Visual Studio C# project?

Comment: you should add that dll into your references folder

Comment: All in all you should invest some time learning OOP, visual studio and c# basics. It will be worth!

Comment: @LuisFilipe Yes, I agree. I have been doing school and professional work in Java, JavaScript, C++ and C# for about a year now. I think I got the OOP basics down. I like C# and visual studio the best. It makes the most sense and is/was the easiest to get used to. And the best part is that I don't have to code the gui.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should ***add a reference***.

In the project you are working on, you can add a reference to the dll (or a library) by doing navigating to:

> (Project)->References->Add Reference

[You will find Properties, References and [class]files below your project]

According to your question, you should add "UltraID3Lib.dll" to your project references and use it through adding a `using` on top of your project files like this:

```
using HundredMilesSoftware.UltraID3Lib;
```

After you have successfully added the resource you should build the project and it will copy all the necessary files to your output directory (bin/Release or bin/Debug).

Comment: Once I add the reference, does it use the file path to the dll or does it copy it somewhere else? Let's say if it was on a thumb drive when I made the reference will it not be able to use it (find it) if I unplug the thumb drive?

Comment: @fredsbend: On successful adding of a reference, it should be copied to your output directory(say, bin/Release or bin/Debug) when you build your application.

Comment: There are no .dll files in my output directory, though I have successfully added the reference and can use the methods now. I have a bin/Debug directory, but there are no new files in it.

Comment: did you build your application? After successful referencing, you should "build" your application (solution or sln) by going Build->Build Solution.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I saved the solution, but did not build it yet. It added the .dll and the .xml to the Debug directory. Thank you. +1 and selection.

Answer (score 1):

## Step 1:

> Open Debug Folder (you can find it In your project Folder => Bin => Debug). Copy .dll >files there.

### Step2:

> In Solution Explorer Right Click on References => Add References
>   Go to Project Tab.
>   Under the Project Tab you can find Added References (References added In Debug Folder). >Simply select needed references & hit OK. You're done

Happy Coding....! :D