# Get file details like title name

Tags: .net, wpf, system.io.fileinfo

So I'm Building a search class, I need to get the title ("Titel" in picture) out from these files(see pic).
[image]

Currently I'm getting the "Navn" from FileInfo.Name
Can anyone help?

Comment: How? in which OS? from which programming language? We need some more info to answer this..

Comment: .NET, Windows 8 can be inferred from screenshot and tags

Comment: Why not just look at the good example on the [`FileInfo` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) page on MSDN?

Comment: @BasBrekelmans: it may be inferred, but I believe the OPs have to put cleary everything that is required to understand the question and the context of the question

Comment: Opalenzuale: Programming language is C# build in WPF.
Sheridan: Didnt get help there, but sure you can help me out from there since you referre to it? =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are ID3 tags and cannot be queried using FileInfo.

You might use a library like TagLibSharp: see: [View/edit ID3 data for MP3 files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68283/view-edit-id3-data-for-mp3-files)

Comment: Thank you, what I've been searching for :)